# Display list view in all of available space

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, layout

I am trying to have my list view display all the way to the bottom row which contains the previous and back buttons but an element seems to block it from doing so. This element shows in the debug view (screenshot below).

EDIT: If I get rid of the question text, the list displays normally, but I still can't explain the behaviour.

I have the following flutter layout:
[image]

The way it displays is as follows:
[image]

How do I get rid of that element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the question text from Expanded, to a simple container fixed it. There was no need for Expanded since it was already bounded horizontally by the parent (Column).